# AWS ECS: Is there a way for code inside a task container to set some custom status for outside services to read?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am building a file processing service in AWS and here is what I have now as a manager-worker architecture:

1. A nodejs application running in an EC2 instance, serving as a manager node; In this EC2 instance, there is also a RabbitMQ service hosting a job queue
2. An ECS service running multiple task containers and the containers are also running nodejs code. The code in every task container runs some custom business logic for processing a job. The task containers get the jobs from the above RabbitMQ job queue. When there are jobs enqueued in the RabbitMQ queue, the jobs are assigned to the ECS task containers and the ECS task container would start processing the job.

Now, this ECS service should scale up or down. When there are no jobs in the queue (which happens very frequently), I just want to keep one worker container alive so that I can save budgets.

When there is a large number of jobs arriving at the manager and enqueue into the job queue, the manager has to figure out how to scale up.

It needs to figure out how many new worker container to add into the ECS service. And to do this, it needs to know:

1. the number of task containers in the ECS service now;
2. the status of each container: is it currently processing a job?

This second point leads to my question: is there a way to set a custom status to the task, such that this status can be read by the application in EC2 instance through some AWS ECS API?

Comment: If there are lots of messages in the queue, and the containers are constantly polling the queue for new jobs, what possible scenario would there be where there are tasks just sitting around not currently processing a job?

Comment: @MarkB  When there are no jobs in the queue (which happens very frequently), I just want to keep one worker container alive so that I can save budgets. The reason I use ECS is precisely this - additional worker nodes are turned on only when needed.

Comment: That's the opposite of the scenario you outlined in your question. Your question is asking about scale-up metrics, and your comment outlines a scenario where you would obviously want to scale-up because you only have 1 worker running. Again I ask, why do you need to know if containers are processing a job in order to know if you should add more containers? If there are jobs in the queue, and your auto-scaling service decides it needs to scale-up based on the jobs in the queue, why would you not assume that all current containers are currently processing a job?

Comment: @MarkB  Thanks for the detailed follow-up.  You are right - the question itself is not valid to begin with.  It's been a long day for me and I was just confusing myself.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkB  Say I want to track which step a worker container has reached in processing the job and if it has reached a late step in the process , I do not add new workers.  Does this scenario justify the question?  Out of curiosity, I want to learn if there is such an API in ECS for me to use.

Comment: There is definitely not any such API in ECS. You would have to build that yourself using something like a DynamoDB table that tasks would update as they were processing jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, there isn't any built in AWS method to do this. I have two suggestions that I hope can accomplish what you want to do:

1. Create a lambda function that runs on a regular interval that calls into your RabbitMQ api to check the queue length. Then it can use the ECS API to set the desired task count for your service. You can have as much control as you want over the thresholds and strategy for scaling in your code.
2. Consider using AWS Batch. The compute backend for Batch is also ECS based, so it might not be such a big change. Long running jobs where you want to scale up and down the processing is its sweet spot. If you want, you can queue the work directly in Batch and skip Rabbit. Or, if you still need to use Rabbit you could create a smaller job in Lambda or anywhere else, that pulls the messages out and creates AWS Batch jobs for each. Batch supports running on EC2 ECS clusters, but it can also use Fargate, so it could simplify your management even further.